# My screen wrap code is not working properly

Tags: unity, c#

I am new to Game Dev.

I am trying to make a asteroid shooter like game with screen wrap (in unity 2017.4)

But the screen wrap code is not working well

View Faulty Screen wrap in action by clicking the [Video Link](https://www.wevideo.com/view/2218792174).

Instead of teleporting the the object to the other side of the screen it is choosing a random point.

I made a classic WASD movement and point towards mouse script.

Then I put the following script on the player with guidance from [envato tuts +](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/create-an-asteroids-like-screen-wrapping-effect-with-unity--gamedev-15055)

Script for reference️

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScreenWrapper : MonoBehaviour
{
   Renderer[] renderers;
   public Camera mainCamera;
   Vector3 newPos;

   Vector3 viewPortPos;

   void Start()
   {
      renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
      newPos = transform.position;
   }

   bool isOffScreen()
   {
      foreach (Renderer renderer in renderers)
      {
         if (renderer.isVisible)
         {
            return false;
         }
      }

      return true;
   }

   void Update()
   {

      viewPortPos = mainCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);

      if (isOffScreen())
      {
         if (viewPortPos.x > 1 || viewPortPos.x < 0)
         {
            newPos.x = -newPos.x;
         }

         if (viewPortPos.y > 1 || viewPortPos.y < 0)
         {
            newPos.y = -newPos.y;
         }

         transform.position = newPos;
         newPos = transform.position;
      }
   }
}
```

Download Project for reference by clicking the [link](https://forum.brackeys.com/uploads/011/AO8JQE9MHMRU.zip).

Hope you Help me figure out my mistake.

Comment: It won't answer your question, but Unity 2017 is pretty outdated now. You should consider updating to 2019.4.x or 2020.3.x

Comment: But due to some reason my Windows PC(64-bit, 4GB RAM) is handling unity versions greater than 2017 very slow.